# Print out UPDATE and DELETE query

Tags: php

At bottom of INSERT php/sql code, i use echo to print out query result to fix errors, in this way:

```
... code ...
$result = MYSQL_QUERY($sqlQuery);
echo $sqlQuery
```

Exist a solution to print out UPDATE and DELETE queries like above?

TKS All

Comment: Just print them out the same way? I assume you have the update/delete queries stored in another variable called `$sqlQuery`. Just print that out?
Also, please note that StackOverflow is not the place to ask "how do I do this". You need to provide tangible efforts to solve the matter and tell us the outcome/how you did it. [How to ask a quesition](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Marcus, that's correct. I asked this because when i try to print out, i have blank results...

Comment: Please show the relevant code for your effort so that I have something to work with.

Comment: $update = mysql_query("
            UPDATE mod_document_images
               SET image_os_res = '$checkbox_os', 
                   image_ne_aut = '$checkbox_ne',
                   image_ge_cat = '$image_gen_cat'
            WHERE image_id =".$image_id);       
            $result = mysql_query($update);

Comment: The question actually makes no sense. The content of $sqlQuery will always be text regardless of whether you code a 'SELECT...', 'INSERT...', 'UPDATE...', 'DELETE...'. So just do the same thing you already do

Comment: You're running `mysql_query()` twice: `$update = mysql_query( "..." ); mysql_query( $update );` The `$update` variable should contain *only* a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments to OP, you need to change the way you run the query if you want this to work. Below is how I would've done it.

```
$update = "UPDATE mod_document_images SET image_os_res = '" . $checkbox_os . "', image_ne_aut = '" . $checkbox_ne . "', image_ge_cat = '" . $image_gen_cat . "' WHERE image_id = " . $image_id;

echo "Query: " . $query; // Echo the query containing the variables supplied
$result = mysql_query($update); // Run the update and store the result in $result
```